# Apportable soundeffect delay

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, apportable

I am have problems when playing sound effects using the Apportable SDK.

All of the wav sound effects are preloaded using SimpleAudioEngine.

This is the code i am using

```
- @ init
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"sound.wav"];

- @ event
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"sound.wav" pitch:1.0f pan:0.0f gain:1.0f];
```

It plays flawlessly on IPhone 4/4S/5S but when porting to android it gets a delay by 0.5 to 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

usually this problem can be solved by lowering the sample rate of the sound effect or, unfortunately, using a better device. might i ask which device you're using?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have two devices for testing and it seems that the device with lower performance and fps handles the sound effects badly.

**Old HTC** with Android 2.3 works **GOOD** --

**Samsung Galaxy S2** with Android 4.x creates **DELAY**.